# A question about the execution sequence in Javascript Iterator

Tags: javascript, iterator, sequence

```
class iteratorWithoutG {
  [Symbol.iterator]() {
    let val = 0;
    let threshold = 10;
    return {
      next() {
        if(val >= threshold) {
          console.log('iteratorWithoutG is finished');
          return {
            done: true,
            value: undefined
          } 
        }
        return {
          done: false,
          value: val++
        }
      },
      return() {
        return {
          done: true,
          value: undefined
        } 
      }
    }
  }
}
const iWithoutG = new iteratorWithoutG(10);
console.log([...iWithoutG]);
```

I was learning things about the JS iterator, and I got this:

```
iteratorWithoutG is finished
[ 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9 ]
```

I wondered why the String was displayed before the Array, so I added some logs:

```
class iteratorWithoutG {
  [Symbol.iterator]() {
    let val = 0;
    let threshold = 10;
    return {
      next() {
        if(val >= threshold) {
          console.log('iteratorWithoutG is finished');
          console.log(Date.now())
          return {
            done: true,
            value: undefined
          } 
        }
        return {
          done: false,
          value: (val++, Date.now())
        }
      },
      return() {
        return {
          done: true,
          value: undefined
        } 
      }
    }
  }
}
```

This time I get this message:

```
iteratorWithoutG is finished
1610466807875
[ 1610466807872,
  1610466807872,
  1610466807872,
  1610466807872,
  1610466807872,
  1610466807872,
  1610466807872,
  1610466807872,
  1610466807872,
  1610466807872 ]
```

So the string was in fact generated after the Array, but how can it be displayed before the Array?? Was the Array stored somewhere?

Comment: This has nothing to do with iterators. In `f(g())`, the function `g` is executed first and its logs will occur before those of `f`. In your case, `f` is `console.log` and array spread, whereas `g` is the iterator `next` method.

Comment: "*So the string was in fact generated after the Array*" - what makes you assume that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This line:

```js
console.log([...iWithoutG]);
```

De-sugars to:

```
{
  let arr = [];
  for (const e of iWithoutG) {
    arr.push(e);
  }
  console.log(arr);
}
```

That means that first, the array is created and populated, and only then `console.log()` is called. So the iterator finishes before the call to `console.log()`.

Full order of events:

1. The array and the iterator are initialized.
2. The iterator's `next()` method is called until it's done and the results are pushed into the array.
3. The iterator finishes.
4. The array is logged to the console.